# Complex function form of $\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm following the lecture notes of $18.04$ in OCW and one of the examples involves calculating the real integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}$ the first step of the procedure is turning $\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}$ into $\frac{1}{(z^2-1)^2(z^2+i)^2}$, I understood the rest, but I can't see how this step was made even though it's just a simple factorization problem, when I opened the expression I got $z^4 -2z^2+2i(z^3-z)$ which is close but not there.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The variable from $(x^2+1)^2$ is $x$, whereas the variable from $(z^2-1)^2(z^2+i)^2$ is $z$. Besides, $\deg(x^2+1)^2=4$ is $x$, whereas $\deg(z^2-1)^2(z^2+i)^2=8$.

Comment: Where did you see this?  Surely it is $(z-i)^2(z+i)^2$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in the factorisation and there are two different variables. We have

$$\frac{1}{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{(x+i)(x-i)}$$

so

$$\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}=\frac{1}{(x+i)^2(x-i)^2}$$

See page $8$ of the [this](https://math.mit.edu/%7Ejorloff/18.04/notes/topic4.pdf).

---

Also

$$\frac{1}{x^4+1}=\frac{1}{(x^2+i)(x^2-i)}$$

Comment: Before you accuse OCW lecture notes of making a mistake in the factorisation, have a look at the actual [pdf](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-04-complex-variables-with-applications-spring-2018/lecture-notes/MIT18_04S18_topic9.pdf) where it never actually occurred.

Comment: I didn't accuse OCW lecture notes of making a mistake, in fact I linked the exact question above. I'm just stating that there is a mistake in the OP's factorisation :-)

Answer (score 0):

Write the integrand as 1 over ((z-i) squared times (z+i) squared). Then using residuum theory find the residuum of the integrand at i, which is -i/4. Your closed path of integration should be a semicircle (in the region with a positive imaginary part), together with the whole infinite x-axis as the diameter. The integral along the circle part of the path does not contribute anything, and the rest is just your requested integral. This is, according to residuum theory,  equal to 2 Pi i times the sum of all the residua within the encircled path, what is just -i/4 only, so the integral will be 2 Pi i times -i/4, which is just Pi half (what is the opinion of Mathematica too!).